# Dump stack and heap memory to file, then load it back into RAM?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, stack, heap-memory

As the question states. I am certain that it is possible, but I can't find information on the subject.

I'm doing this as an experiment right now, the idea is basically to do the following scenario:

1. boot up linux (just because I don't like windows)
2. do some random stuff
3. dump stack and heap memory to 1 or 2 files
4. do some other random stuff
5. load dump(s) back into memory

The effect I am trying to achieve is basically hibernate a system state, but keep the system running, then wake the previous state. Not sure where I would be able to use this, but it sounds like geeky fun.

EDIT: I thought searching for sysctl hibernate sources would help, but I can't even seem to find those.

Update:
So far I have found the following information:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/swsusp.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate
- https://alioth-archive.debian.org/git/collab-maint/hibernate.git.tar.xz

Continuing the search...

I think this is where I need to dig:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=swsusp

Also, as @Useless stated in the comments, here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/power/hibernate.c?h=v5.14-rc6

Comment: The hibernated state would include the inode and page caches, right? I don't see how this would work if the filesystem changed during stage 4, and they're now out of date. (By "work" I mean "avoid crashing and/or trashing your filesystems)

Comment: This is something I want to experiment with, and it's fine if the system crashes for now - it's just something I want to work on with no defined goals.

Comment: You can find the kernel code in [power/hibernate.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/power/hibernate.c?h=v5.14-rc6) (that's the latest mainline, 5.14-rc6 at the time of writing).

Comment: I don't think you can reasonably do it outside the kernel, since you need to save all the kernel state plus the state of every running process, for all users

Comment: Sounds about right, I'll dig around some more. If you write it down as an answer, I can accept it. P.S. Thank you for your fast responses and help!

Comment: At this level of abstraction there is no stack and heap memory, there is just memory. Some of it is used for stacks and some of it is used for heaps but that is not your concern. Yes, it sounds like hibernate but slightly different.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that all "processes" are also just bits and bytes in memory at this level?

Comment: Yes - with the exception of hardware state, which should mostly only affect drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: I thought searching for sysctl hibernate sources would help, but I can't even seem to find those

It'll need to be done in the kernel, since there's a load of kernel & driver state, and it needs access to all running processes.

You can start from [power/hibernate.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/power/hibernate.c).

If you just skip the call to `swsusp_arch_suspend()` in`create_image()`, you should be most of the way to creating the image and then immediately resuming.

You just need to figure out how to:

1. keep the hibernation state around that presumably now gets destroyed on resumption
2. run the restore/thaw half of the code later, when you're not already suspended

Comment: I believe that the image is being deleted by swsusp_free(), can't seem to find its definition though... maybe it's platform-specific, and loaded as a module depending on the platform?

Comment: I don't have a local clone to hand, but if you download one, a recursive grep should find it for you ...